# Why is hugo looking in the wrong directory for layouts?

Tags: hugo

In my hugo project I have the file tree

- content

  - nav

    - technology.md
  - pages

    - bar.md
- layouts

  - nav

    - single.html
    - baseof.html
  - pages

    - single.html
    - baseof.html

But when I run the hugo server with verbose mode I get the warnings

```
WARN: Unable to locate layout for page nav/technology.md: [technology/single.html _default/single.html theme/technology/single.html theme/_default/single.html _default/single.html]
WARN: nav/technology.html is rendered empty
```

Why is hugo looking for `technology/single.html` instead of `nav/single.html` when pages works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason for this was because in my markdown files I was using the option `type = "technology"` which conflicted with the built in option `type`.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify things in your case, 'technology' is not a type, but rather 'nav' is correct and default type. However you can override the default type, in your case, you can use 'pages' instead of the default 'nav'.